# Search an array and make numbered list of found and not found words, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, search

Write an application that searches for words in an array and creates a new array of found words and an array of search words that are not found. The application will display the new arrays of found and not-found words every time a new word is entered.

The provided array is in my code. I'm getting the lists to work but the words I'm getting back are all "undefined." (I have the form set up in my HTML) Hints on what I'm missing to get the "undefined" results? Thanks!

```
//Global variable for array
var wordsCollection = ["JavaScript", "was", "developed", "by", "Brendan", "Eich", "at", "Netscape", "as",
    "the", "in-page", "scripting", "language", "for", "Navigator", "2.", "It", "is", "a",
    "remarkably", "expressive", "dynamic", "programming", "language.", "Because",
    "of", "its", "linkage", "to", "web", "browsers", "it", "instantly", "became",
    "massively", "popular.", "It", "never", "got", "a", "trial", "period", "in", "which",
    "it", "could", "be", "corrected", "and", "polished", "based", "on", "actual", "use.",
    "The", "language", "is", "powerful", "and", "flawed."];    

function exercise11Part1() 
{
    var output;
    var exercises8form;
    var searchWord;
    var index = "";
    var valueFound = false;
    var foundWords = []; 
    var notFoundWords = [];
    var foundWordsList;
    var notFoundWordsList;

    exercises8form = document.getElementById("exercises8formId");

    searchWord = exercises8form.wordSearch.value;

    foundWordsList = document.getElementById("foundWordsListId");
    notFoundWordsList = document.getElementById("notFoundWordsListId");

    for (index = 0; index < wordsCollection.length; index++)
    {
        if (searchWord === wordsCollection[index])
        {
        valueFound = true;
        break;
        }
    }

    if (valueFound)
    {
        foundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        foundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[index] + "</li>";
    }
    else
    {
        notFoundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        notFoundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + notFoundWords[index] + "</li>";
    }

    return false;
}
```

I'm still getting ... not the correct output. What am I missing?

```
//Global variable for array
var wordsCollection = ["JavaScript", "was", "developed", "by", "Brendan", "Eich", "at", "Netscape", "as",
    "the", "in-page", "scripting", "language", "for", "Navigator", "2.", "It", "is", "a",
    "remarkably", "expressive", "dynamic", "programming", "language.", "Because",
    "of", "its", "linkage", "to", "web", "browsers", "it", "instantly", "became",
    "massively", "popular.", "It", "never", "got", "a", "trial", "period", "in", "which",
    "it", "could", "be", "corrected", "and", "polished", "based", "on", "actual", "use.",
    "The", "language", "is", "powerful", "and", "flawed."];    

var foundWords = []; 
var notFoundWords = [];

function exercise11Part1() 
{
    var exercises8form;
    var searchWord;
    var index = "";
    var valueFound = false;

    var foundWordsList;
    var notFoundWordsList;

    exercises8form = document.getElementById("exercises8formId");
    searchWord = exercises8form.enteredString.value;

    foundWordsListOutput = document.getElementById("foundWordsListId");
    notFoundWordsListOutput = document.getElementById("notFoundWordsListId");

    for (index = 0; index < wordsCollection.length; index++)
    {
        if (searchWord === wordsCollection[index])
        {
            foundWords.push(searchWord);
            foundWordsList += "<li>" + foundWords[index] + "</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            notFoundWords.push(searchWord); 
            notFoundWordsList += "<li>" + notFoundWords[index] + "</li>";
        }
    }

    foundWordsListOutput.innerHTML = foundWordsList; 
    notFoundWordsListOutput.innerHTML = notFoundWordsList;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment...

Comment: It def is--intro to JavaScript. I've got it kind of done? (Except it's returning "undefined")

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [`indexOf` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

```
var foundWords = [],    // Don't declare these in the function,
    notFoundWords = []; // That resets them each time you call the function.

function exercise11Part1() {    
    var exercises8form = document.getElementById("exercises8formId"),
        searchWord = exercises8form.wordSearch.value,
        foundWordsList = document.getElementById("foundWordsListId"),
        notFoundWordsList = document.getElementById("notFoundWordsListId");

    var index = wordsCollection.indexOf(searchWord);
    if (index !== -1) {
        foundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        foundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[index] + "</li>";
    } else {
        notFoundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        notFoundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + notFoundWords[index] + "</li>";
    }

    return false;
}
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the `searchWord` isn't found in the array, or the word's index in the array if it *is* found.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (index = 0; index < wordsCollection.length; index++)
    {
        if (searchWord === wordsCollection[index])
        {
        valueFound = true;
          foundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        }
        else
        {
          notFoundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
        }

    }
    for (word in foundWords){
       foundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[word] + "</li>";
    }
    for (word in notFoundWords){
       notFoundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + notFoundWords[word] + "</li>";

    }
```

Comment: Nope, he's declared the `index` outside of the loop, and he's breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
if (valueFound)
{
    foundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
    foundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[index] + "</li>";
}
```

substituting

```
if (searchWord === wordsCollection[index])
        {
        valueFound = true;
        break;
        }
```

for

```
if (searchWord === wordsCollection[index]) {
    foundWords.push(wordsCollection[index]);
    foundWordsList.innerHTML += "<li>" + foundWords[index] + "</li>";
}
```